# How to fix ‘Cannot create a DbSet for 'DM_NCC_ThueSuat' because this type is not included in the model for the context’ error in C# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, abp

I have a code block regards get a list like that in aspnetzero:

```
public async Task<List<DMNCCThueSuatDto>> GetDSThueSuat()
{
    using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(null))
    {
        var lstthueSuat = await _dmThueSuatRepository.Query(t => t.Where(i => 
        i.IsDeleted == false)).OrderBy("thuesuat_ma asc").ToListAsync();
        return ObjectMapper.Map<List<DMNCCThueSuatDto>>(lstthueSuat);
    }
}
```

I expected a list of DMNCCThueSuatDto is returned but the error

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'DM_NCC_ThueSuat' because this type is not
>   included in the model for the context.

is always displayed.

Also, i had myown a declaration 
    public virtual DbSet DS_ThueSuat { get; set; }
in my DBContext.
In my mariadb database, i had a table called "vs_dm_ncc_thuesuat"
and i have already declare a class for mapping to the table above

```
namespace VS.vHoaDon.Domains.DanhMuc.DMNhaCungCap
{
    [Table("vs_dm_ncc_thuesuat")]
    [MultiTenancySide(MultiTenancySides.Host)]
    public class DM_NCC_ThueSuat : FullAuditedEntity
    {
        public int ThueSuat_Ma { get; set; }
        public string ThueSuat_Ten { get; set; }
        public int ThueSuat_GiaTri { get; set; }
        public bool ThueSuat_HieuLuc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ThueSuat_BatDau { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ThueSuat_KetThuc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't know why?
Any helps is appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: The error is quite clear.  You don't have a property of type `DbSet<DM_NCC_ThueSuat>` in your DbContext subtype.

Comment: Thanks @David Browne but i had one in my DBContext.
just like this: 
    public virtual DbSet<DM_NCC_ThueSuat> DS_ThueSuat { get; set; }

Comment: What does dmThueSuatRepository look like?

Comment: Here you go @ David Browne

    public class DM_NCC_ThueSuatRepository : 
        VSRepositoryBase<DM_NCC_ThueSuat>
            {
                public                  
    DM_NCC_ThueSuatRepository(IDbContextProvider<VSDbContext> 
    dbContextProvider) : base(dbContextProvider)
            {
            }
        }

Comment: Even, i deleted dmThueSuatRepository and use IRepository<DM_NCC_TinhThanh> 
but the error still happenning.

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the body of the question, and include a minimal, complete repro of the issue.